# Finding CN of users in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, distinguishedname

I'm trying to find the Base DN of the user that can access or controls all the users in Active Directory so I can put it in my LDAP.

Usually someone will give me this, and it looks like `DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com`

But the admin is not available, so I don't know how to find this in Active Directory.

I'm looking for a step by step to find this info. Which tree and tabs to open and how to construct it.
My user is: admin, the server is: `controller-16.domain.company.com`
But I don't know if they added OU or groups or something else

I know that this:

```
CN=admin,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com
```

does not work. Nor does:

```
DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com
```

If the Base DN works on [Gawor's LDAP Browser](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8652/gawors-excellent-ldap-browsereditor-v282), then it will work for my LDAP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try my [Beavertail ADSI browser](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/csharp/beavertail.html) - it should show you the current AD tree, and from it, you should be able to figure out the path and all.

[image]

Or if you're on .NET 3.5, using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, you could also do it programmatically:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

This would create a basic, default domain context and you should be able to peek at its properties and find a lot of stuff from it.

Or:

```
UserPrincipal myself = UserPrincipal.Current;
```

This will give you a `UserPrincipal` object for yourself, again, with a ton of properties to inspect. I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for - but you most likely will be able to find it on the context or the user principal somewhere!

Comment: Worked perfectly, I found out I was missing an OU to get to the users.

Comment: Tools > Options: `LDAP://RootDSE plus all available domains`

Answer (score 1):

Most common AD default design is to have a container, cn=users just after the root of the domain.  Thus a DN might be:

`cn=admin,cn=users,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com`

Also, you might have sufficient rights in an LDAP bind to connect anonymously, and query for `(cn=admin)`.  If so, you should get the full DN back in that query.

Answer (score -1):

CN refers to class name, so put in your LDAP query CN=Users. Should work.

Comment: I believe CN in this context actually refers to Common Name, not Class Name.